# Windows Batch: How to add Host-Entries?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, hosts

I want to use this batch script to add new entries into my host file automatically by using [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) batch.

Unfortunately, the script **just adds one single line to the hosts file**, also when i run the script as a administrator, so what's wrong?

```
@echo off

set hostspath=%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

echo 62.116.159.4 ns1.intranet.de >> %hostspath%
echo 217.160.113.37 ns2.intranet.de >> %hostpath%
echo 89.146.248.4 ns3.intranet.de >> %hostpath%
echo 74.208.254.4 ns4.intranet.de >> %hostpath%

exit
```

Comment: Which one does it add to the file. The first one or the last one?

Comment: Awesome question, glad to find the info ready and waiting.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I would do it this way, so you won't end up with duplicate entries if the script is run multiple times.

```
@echo off

SET NEWLINE=^& echo.

FIND /C /I "ns1.intranet.de" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^62.116.159.4 ns1.intranet.de>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

FIND /C /I "ns2.intranet.de" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^217.160.113.37 ns2.intranet.de>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

FIND /C /I "ns3.intranet.de" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^89.146.248.4 ns3.intranet.de>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

FIND /C /I "ns4.intranet.de" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^74.208.254.4 ns4.intranet.de>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Comment: Definitive answer here.  Cheers!

Comment: `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ...` can be used which reads as `IF ERRORLEVEL >= 1 THEN`.  Taken from http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html.  Eliminates the need to use `NEQ`.

Comment: for some reason this is not stopping me from adding duplicate entries

Comment: :1
cls
SET /P WEBSITE=Enter the name of the website to add:
SET HOME=     127.0.0.1 
SET NEWLINE=^& echo.
SET BLOCKEDSITE=%HOME% %WEBSITE%

FIND /C /I %BLOCKEDSITE% %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^%BLOCKEDSITE%>>%WINDIR

%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
ECHO Website blocked
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul
GOTO LOOP

Answer (score 25):

Plain typo. `hostspath` vs `hostpath` ;)

```
@echo off 

set `hostspath`=%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts 

echo 62.116.159.4 ns1.intranet.de >> `%hostspath%`   
echo 217.160.113.37 ns2.intranet.de >> `%hostpath%`  
echo 89.146.248.4 ns3.intranet.de >> `%hostpath%`   
echo 74.208.254.4 ns4.intranet.de >> `%hostpath%`   

exit
```

Answer (score 22):

Here is my modification of @rashy above. The script does the following:

- it verifies you have access, if not, requests it
- allows you to enter in multiple hosts in a list
- loops through the list
- It finds the line containing the the domain name and removes it, then re-adds it (incase the ip has changed since the last time the script was run).
- if the domain isn't there, it just adds it.

This is the script:

```
@echo off
TITLE Modifying your HOSTS file
COLOR F0
ECHO.


:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"="
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------

:LOOP
SET Choice=
SET /P Choice="Do you want to modify HOSTS file ? (Y/N)"

IF NOT '%Choice%'=='' SET Choice=%Choice:~0,1%

ECHO.
IF /I '%Choice%'=='Y' GOTO ACCEPTED
IF /I '%Choice%'=='N' GOTO REJECTED
ECHO Please type Y (for Yes) or N (for No) to proceed!
ECHO.
GOTO Loop


:REJECTED
ECHO Your HOSTS file was left unchanged>>%systemroot%\Temp\hostFileUpdate.log
ECHO Finished.
GOTO END


:ACCEPTED
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
::Create your list of host domains
set LIST=(diqc.oca wiki.oca)
::Set the ip of the domains you set in the list above
set diqc.oca=192.168.111.6
set wiki.oca=192.168.111.4
:: deletes the parentheses from LIST
set _list=%LIST:~1,-1%
::ECHO %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts > tmp.txt
for  %%G in (%_list%) do (
    set  _name=%%G
    set  _value=!%%G!
    SET NEWLINE=^& echo.
    ECHO Carrying out requested modifications to your HOSTS file
    ::strip out this specific line and store in tmp file
    type %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts | findstr /v !_name! > tmp.txt
    ::re-add the line to it
    ECHO %NEWLINE%^!_value! !_name!>>tmp.txt
    ::overwrite host file
    copy /b/v/y tmp.txt %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
    del tmp.txt
)
ipconfig /flushdns
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO Finished, you may close this window now.
ECHO You should now open Chrome and go to "chrome://net-internals/#dns" (without quotes)
ECHO     then click the "clear host cache" button
GOTO END

:END
ECHO.
ping -n 11 192.0.2.2 > nul
EXIT
```

Comment: Just in case anyone uses this almost perfect script, I found a minor issue with it when it requires the permission and you are passing parameters into the script. You will need to get rid of the spaces i.e. set params=%&:"="

Answer (score 7):

Create a new **addHostEntry.bat** file with the following content in it:

```
@echo off
TITLE Modifying your HOSTS file
COLOR F0
ECHO.

:LOOP
SET Choice=
SET /P Choice="Do you want to modify HOSTS file ? (Y/N)"

IF NOT '%Choice%'=='' SET Choice=%Choice:~0,1%

ECHO.
IF /I '%Choice%'=='Y' GOTO ACCEPTED
IF /I '%Choice%'=='N' GOTO REJECTED
ECHO Please type Y (for Yes) or N (for No) to proceed!
ECHO.
GOTO Loop


:REJECTED
ECHO Your HOSTS file was left unchanged>>%systemroot%\Temp\hostFileUpdate.log
ECHO Finished.
GOTO END


:ACCEPTED
SET NEWLINE=^& echo.
ECHO Carrying out requested modifications to your HOSTS file
FIND /C /I "mydomain.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1    mydomain.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
ECHO Finished
GOTO END


:END
ECHO.
ping -n 11 127.0.0.1 > nul
EXIT
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this answer in case someone else would like to store the host entry set in a txt file formatted like the normal host file. This looks for a TAB delimiter. This is based off of the answers from @Rashy and @that0n3guy. The differences can be noticed around the FOR command.

```
@echo off
TITLE Modifying your HOSTS file
ECHO.

:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"="
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------

:LOOP
SET Choice=
SET /P Choice="Do you want to modify HOSTS file ? (Y/N)"

IF NOT '%Choice%'=='' SET Choice=%Choice:~0,1%

ECHO.
IF /I '%Choice%'=='Y' GOTO ACCEPTED
IF /I '%Choice%'=='N' GOTO REJECTED
ECHO Please type Y (for Yes) or N (for No) to proceed!
ECHO.
GOTO Loop


:REJECTED
ECHO Your HOSTS file was left unchanged.
ECHO Finished.
GOTO END


:ACCEPTED
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
::Create your list of host domains
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=  " %%A in (%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\storedhosts.txt) do (
    SET _host=%%B
    SET _ip=%%A
    SET NEWLINE=^& echo.
    ECHO Adding !_ip!       !_host!
    REM REM ::strip out this specific line and store in tmp file
    type %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts | findstr /v !_host! > tmp.txt
    REM REM ::re-add the line to it
    ECHO %NEWLINE%^!_ip!        !_host! >> tmp.txt
    REM ::overwrite host file
    copy /b/v/y tmp.txt %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
    del tmp.txt 
)

ipconfig /flushdns
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO Finished, you may close this window now.
GOTO END

:END
ECHO.
PAUSE
EXIT
```

**Example "storedhosts.txt" (tab delimited)**

```
127.0.0.1   mysite.com
168.1.64.2  yoursite.com
192.1.0.1   internalsite.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime I have to work from home and connect to office through vpn. Internal domain names should be resolved to different IPs at home. There are several names that have to be changed between office and home. For example:

```
At office, a => 192.168.0.3, b => 192.168.0.52. 
At home, a => 10.6.1.7, b => 10.4.5.23.
```

My solution is to create two files: C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts-home and C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts-office. Each of them contains set of name-to-IP mapping. From **Administrator** **PowerShell**, When I work at the office, execute

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> cp .\drivers\etc\hosts-office .\drivers\etc\hosts
```

When I arrive at home, execute

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> cp .\drivers\etc\hosts-home .\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Answer (score -4):

**Well I write a script which works very well.**

```
> @echo off TITLE Modifying your HOSTS file COLOR F0 ECHO.
> 
> :LOOP SET Choice= SET /P Choice="Do you want to modify HOSTS file ?
> (Y/N)"
> 
> IF NOT '%Choice%'=='' SET Choice=%Choice:~0,1%
> 
> ECHO. IF /I '%Choice%'=='Y' GOTO ACCEPTED IF /I '%Choice%'=='N' GOTO
> REJECTED ECHO Please type Y (for Yes) or N (for No) to proceed! ECHO.
> GOTO Loop
> 
> 
> :REJECTED ECHO Your HOSTS file was left
> unchanged>>%systemroot%\Temp\hostFileUpdate.log ECHO Finished. GOTO
> END
> 
> 
> :ACCEPTED SET NEWLINE=^& echo. ECHO Carrying out requested
> modifications to your HOSTS file FIND /C /I "www.youtube.com"
> %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO
> %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0
> ECHO 127.0.0.1    www.youtube.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> FIND /C /I "youtube.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> youtube.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.zacebookpk.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.zacebookpk.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "zacebookpk.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> zacebookpk.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.proxysite.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.proxysite.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.proxfree.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.proxfree.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.hidemyass.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.hidemyass.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.freeyoutubeproxy.org" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.freeyoutubeproxy.org>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C
> /I "www.facebook.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.facebook.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "facebook.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ
> 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> facebook.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.4everproxy.com " %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1    www.4everproxy.com
> >>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I "4everproxy.com " %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO
> %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0
> ECHO 127.0.0.1    4everproxy.com >>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> FIND /C /I "proxysite.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> proxysite.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "proxfree.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ
> 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> proxfree.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "hidemyass.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> hidemyass.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "freeyoutubeproxy.org" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> freeyoutubeproxy.org>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "unblockvideos.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> unblockvideos.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "proxyone.net" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ
> 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> proxyone.net>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "kuvia.eu" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0
> ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1    kuvia.eu>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> FIND /C /I "kuvia.eu/facebook-proxy"
> %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO
> %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0
> ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> kuvia.eu/facebook-proxy>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C
> /I "hidemytraxproxy.ca" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> hidemytraxproxy.ca>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "github.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0
> ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> github.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "funproxy.net" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ
> 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> funproxy.net>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "en.wikipedia.org" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> en.wikipedia.org>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "wikipedia.org" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> wikipedia.org>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "dronten.proxylistpro.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> dronten.proxylistpro.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C
> /I "proxylistpro.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> proxylistpro.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "zfreez.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0
> ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> zfreez.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "zendproxy.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> zendproxy.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "zalmos.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0
> ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> zalmos.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "zacebookpk.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> zacebookpk.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "youtubeunblockproxy.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> youtubeunblockproxy.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C
> /I "youtubefreeproxy.net" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> youtubefreeproxy.net>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "youliaoren.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> youliaoren.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "xitenow.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ
> 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> xitenow.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.youtubeproxy.pk" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.youtubeproxy.pk>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "youtubeproxy.pk" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> youtubeproxy.pk>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.youproxytube.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.youproxytube.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.webmasterview.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.webmasterview.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "webmasterview.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> webmasterview.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "youproxytube.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> youproxytube.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.vobas.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.vobas.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "vobas.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0
> ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1    vobas.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> FIND /C /I "www.unblockmyweb.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO
> %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0
> ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.unblockmyweb.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "unblockmyweb.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> unblockmyweb.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.unblocker.yt" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.unblocker.yt>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "unblocker.yt" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ
> 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> unblocker.yt>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.unblock.pk" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.unblock.pk>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "unblock.pk" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0
> ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> unblock.pk>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.techgyd.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.techgyd.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "techgyd.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ
> 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> techgyd.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.snapdeal.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.snapdeal.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "snapdeal.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ
> 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> snapdeal.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.site2unblock.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.site2unblock.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "site2unblock.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> site2unblock.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.shopclues.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.shopclues.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "shopclues.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> shopclues.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.proxypk.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.proxypk.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "proxypk.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ
> 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> proxypk.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.proxay.co.uk" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.proxay.co.uk>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "proxay.co.uk" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ
> 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> proxay.co.uk>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.myntra.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.myntra.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "myntra.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0
> ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> myntra.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.maddw.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.maddw.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "maddw.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0
> ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1    maddw.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> FIND /C /I "www.lenskart.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.lenskart.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "lenskart.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ
> 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> lenskart.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.kproxy.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.kproxy.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "kproxy.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0
> ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> kproxy.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.jabong.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.jabong.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "jabong.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0
> ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> jabong.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.flipkart.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.flipkart.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "flipkart.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ
> 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> flipkart.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.facebook-proxyserver.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.facebook-proxyserver.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND
> /C /I "facebook-proxyserver.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO
> %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0
> ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> facebook-proxyserver.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C
> /I "www.dontfilter.us" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.dontfilter.us>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "dontfilter.us" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> dontfilter.us>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts FIND /C /I
> "www.dolopo.net" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF %ERRORLEVEL%
> NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts IF
> %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO 127.0.0.1   
> www.dolopo.net>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts ECHO Finished GOTO
> END
> 
> 
> :END ECHO. ping -n 11 127.0.0.1 > nul EXIT
```

Comment: don't use the back code in front of each line.. that's a mistake. and I am too lazy to remove it.

Comment: you definitely should