# Windows batch to add/replace entry in hosts file

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file

I read this topic [First step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666740/windows-batch-how-to-add-host-entries) which was usefull to begin with. I can add several lines into my hosts file.

I am now trying, without success, to search and replace a string with regular expression. For exemple, if my host file contains "SOMEIP website.com" I would like to modify this line to obtain "NEWIP website.com".

I can find if a line contains "website.com", I currently don't know (if possible) how to get that line and replace the IP address via a regular expression pattern.

```
%windir%\system32\FIND /C /I "website.com" %hostpath% >nul

IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^%server%   website.com>>%hostpath%
```

I'm lost so thank you for your answers :)

Comment: HOSTS requires admin privs to change so you'll need to run your batch file with elevated permissions.

Comment: I will look at 'takeown' and 'grant' to see if it may help with it. Thank you for the iead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/891976 for repl.bat by dbenham which supports regular expression search and replace.

```
type "HOSTS" | repl "\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b website.com" "NEWIP website.com" m >"HOSTS.new"
move /y HOSTS.new HOSTS
```

Repl.bat: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

Comment: That was very helpful, it did exactly what i needed :)

Answer (score 0):

example with [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

```
sed -ri.bak "s/(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9]) website.com/NewIP website.com/ig" hosts
```

`sed` makes a backup copy `hosts.bak`.