# How to remove custom string entries from a host files using cmd?

Tags: cmd, hosts-file

I've entered the following into the hosts file
`127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com
127.0.0.2 www.youtube.com`
how can I delete the above entries from the file using cmd?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Batch: How to add Host-Entries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666740/windows-batch-how-to-add-host-entries)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables please explain how **adding** entries is a duplicate of **removing** entries? Adding is easy, removing is harder ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill - if comments don't make sense, when in doubt, feel free to look at the original version of the question; when I commented, it hadn't been edited

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables that was a quick reply ;) but I see your point ...

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin How is a link to www.google.com constructive?

Comment: @DavidPostill Sorry there's no fault of LittleBobbyTables. When he marked my question duplicate It was in original form that was indeed a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An *ugly* solution:

```
find /v "facebook" hosts | find /v "youtube" hosts > hosts
```

> /V         Displays all lines NOT containing the specified string.

---

see the documentation for [find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/find) ([ss64](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)) system utility