# Change outlook incoming/outgoing server using .bat file

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, outlook-2013

When I am at office I have to use the following outlook incoming/outgoing mail server:

**192.0.0.100**

When I am at home I have to use the following outlook incoming/outgoing mail server:

**mail.pantikidis.com**

I am trying to find a way to use two `.bat` files, the one will automatically set my office setting and the other will set my home settings.

I use windows 10 64bit and outlook 2013.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

1. In your outlook profile you set up the "mail.pantikidis.com".
2. Create a bat to edit the %windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

You look in this thread, there is something very similar : [Windows Batch: How to add Host-Entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666740/windows-batch-how-to-add-host-entries)